# Displaying recordset in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I want to show result of cursor on form.
I have code:

```
(WHEN-MOUSE-CLICK) 
DECLARE
    job EMP.JOB%TYPE;
    sal EMP.SAL%TYPE
    CURSOR getJobs IS
        SELECT job, sal FROM emp;
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN getJobs
   LOOP
       -- append row to data grid or some element
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Which element I can use to do this, or I have to use different method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have as such any grid control in Oracle Forms so instead you have to use a multi record data base block. The benefit is that you don't need to create the cursor and populate by looping through it. Instead forms is doing this for you if you set the block property correctly. In this simple case you only need to set the data source property to emp but if you have a where clause then then you specify that in the where clause property. Please check the Forms help for any further information about block properties. Finally to populate the block you need to move to the database block and the execute the query with Execute_Query builtin:

```
(WHEN-MOUSE-CLICK) 
Go_Block(<NAME_OF_YOUR_BLOCK>);

Execute_Query;
```